# Windows 8 install stuck in reboot cycle

Tags: windows-8, boot, installation

A friend of mine got locked out of a second hand PC she bought due to not having the password so I used the Ctrl+Left Click+Restart method to open the recovery menu/troubleshoot menu and proceeded to reset Windows. The installation went fine, until it showed an error about being restarted unexpectedly, although the pc was on the whole time.

I managed to fix this error (*cmd>regedit method*) and Windows installed a further 46% before rebooting and getting stuck in the pc is on a constant rebooting cycle. Towards the end of the cycle the installation briefly shows (*for about 3 seconds*), and appears stuck on 64%  before rebooting again. This cycle takes around 4min and seems there is no way to exit.

I can't access BIOS, cmd, or any other options. We no longer have a recovery disk. If you know a work around it would be greatly appreciated and we aren't worried about losing all the previous owners data as long as we could salvage the pc without replacing the hard drive or taking it in for repair.

Comment: Have you tried using a fresh installation disc rather than the repair tool?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create an install media](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15088/windows-create-installation-media) and boot from it. Its the only way. You can create this medium through another computer which has internet access (to download the 3 gb iso file).

If you need access to the BIOS in order to boot from dvd or usb, reset it by opening up the pc and find the clear bios jumper or battery (see the manual for its location)

Once booted from the install media, you are given the option to install windows. Choose clean install, not upgrade, because upgrade will require you to boot to windows first, then run the setup.

Comment: Is it possible to take an old version of windows we have on a hard drive and convert it into an install media which can be booted through usb or cd perhaps?

Comment: No. The installer needs to configure your computer and hardware. An old install doesn't provide a bootable medium that will setup your computer with a fresh install. It may be possible to boot into this windows, and from there use the solution I provided to create a bootable media, but you still need internet to download the installation files.